# F5 BIG-IP: Log Profile disabled

Tags: f5, big-ip

Currently I'm setting up a F5 BIG-IP instance and I'm trying to harden the system security-wise. On one virtual server I noticed that "Log Profile" was set to "disabled". What does this exactly mean? Does this mean that absolutely no (security) events are logged? I have set a security policy.

I found the following information on AskF5:

"*By default when you create a security policy using the Deployment wizard, the system associates the log illegal requests profile to the virtual server associated with the policy.*" ([source](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_asm/manuals/product/asm-implementations-11-5-0/12.html))

Does this mean that the log illegal request profile is set even though "Log Profile" is disabled?